# Setting the path in ui-router via $location.path() does not change $state.current

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I am initializing my angular controller with the following code:

```
console.log($state.current);
$location.path('/newpath');
console.log($state.current);
```

The $state.current variable is not being changed though the path has changed. I tried `$scope.$apply()` but this gives me an digest cycle already in progress error.

Note that this doesn't work in my test either:

```
it('should route /newpath to the newpath view', function () {
    $location.path('/newpath');
    $rootScope.$apply();

    console.log($location.path());
    console.log($state.current);
    expect($state.current.templateUrl).to.equal('app/newpath/newpath.html');

});
```

Comment: Are these 3 lines inside of your controller? if yes, then all the code executed there simply belongs to current state... ONLY once this scope is destroyed... new state will be initiated...

Comment: Yes, you're right. I am using all three lines in my controller. But how to do testing then? I have updated my questiog with the code from my test spec.

Comment: But shouldn't changing the location reflect on the state? Currently I am in the process of converting a angular app from angular-routing to ui-router. I have modified this test code from my original angular-router code where the $route.current.templateUrl had changed after setting the new location via $location.path().

Comment: wasn't $state.go(); for changing path in ui-router? maybe im mistaking

Comment: @sbaaaang Yes, and if you read my comments carefully (and my tags), you'll see that I am using ui-router, i.e. I am converting my current app from angular-router to ui-router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a whole day of losing my hair over this, I finally got it solved. The problem seems to be that routing was not working because my view template was not recognized by the test. And the documentation for ui-router states that an invalid templateUrl causes the route to break. Putting the view template into the template cache solved the problem and the route was working and the test passed. Just added this line to the beforeEach function in the spec:

```
 beforeEach(inject(function ($templateCache) {
      $templateCache.put('app/newpath/newpath.html', '');
    }));
```

Comment: Really interesting, great job, sir!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by zszep the problem can be solved by populating the    $templateCache.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($templateCache) {
   $templateCache.put('app/newpath/newpath.html', '');
}));
```

**Alternatively**, you want to simulate the fetching of templates, could can also stub the template requests using $httpBackend.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($httpBackend) {
    $httpBackend.when('GET', 'app/newpath/newpath.html').respond(200, '');
    $httpBackend.flush();
}));
```

**Do not forget to flush()**.

The underlying problem of your observation is, that if it can't load all the templates defined in the markup or the $stateProvider definition, the transition will fail. When that happens, the $state providers properties (such as $state.current) are not being populated.